# How to represent a function that says "send least element to least element and next to next" using a first order formula?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

Suppose that $A$ is a finite set. $<_1$ and $<_2$ are two well-orderings on $A$. 
Suppose that I want to find a formula that repesents the function $F$ that says " send least element in ordering $<_1 $to the least element in the ordering $<_2$ and the next to the next"

What could this formula be?

I think that I can construct such a formula using many "steps". First I define a formula that says "assign least element to least element" and define a formula  for every pair of "next elements" and then take all of those formulas and use them to define the required formula!

Another way is to use "self-reference" to construct the formula in which case we are out of First order formulas..

**My question is**: Is there any simpler way to define it?

Why is such formula important for me?

I need this formula  to apply transfinite recursion theorem to find an isomorphism between any two well-orderings on finite set $A$. I can solve the problem without such a heavy formlism but I'm curious about finding such formula.

Comment: Let $A=\{a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n \}=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\}$ where $a_1<_1a_2<_1\ldots<_1a_n$ and $b_1<_2b_2<_2\ldots<_2b_n$.  $f(a_i)=b_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you want

$$F(a)=\min_{<_2}\big(A\setminus\{F(x):x\in A\text{ and }x<_1 a\}\big)\;,$$

where for $\varnothing\ne S\subseteq A$, $\min\limits_{<_2}S$ is the least element of $S$ with respect to $<_2$.

Comment: I've converted it to First-order formula but it take large space though, thanx :D

Comment: @MathsLover: You're welcome. (I'm not surprised that it was long when fully converted!)